# UITableView Edit Indentation

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm building a pretty simple UITable in my app with custom cells that I'v created. The target language is hebrew. thats why all my tabels are right to left. Everything works fine until I'm changing the table to Edit mode. I'v successfully canceled the delete and the red accessory button becuase thay are in the oppisite direction but the cell get this tiny indentation to the right and part of my cell is not showed.

I tried the return NO; to the function

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but it didn't work.

any suggestions ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just tried this and your function header appears to be correct (at least for English/left-to-right).  I did add a colon between the "shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath" and "(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" - see snippet below.

```
// Override to prevent indentation of cells in editing mode (in theory)
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

I also used the code below to stop the insert/delete functionality and enable the rows can be moved (easily switched off).

```
// Select the editing style of each cell
    - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        // Do not allow inserts / deletes
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
     return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.